youtube broadcast life cycle status stuck in teststarting forever
Youtube broadcast lifecycle status is stuck in 'teststarting' state forever, even after polling for 5 minutes, the state never transitions to 'testing' state. According to youtube help, it is recommended to delete the broadcast and re-create it and repeat the steps all again, but this throws a forbidden error during transition saying 'inactive stream'.
I am making sure that the broadcast transition is triggered only after the stream to which it is bound is in 'active' state. There are no errors of any sort, but still things are not working.
I am sending a HLS feed to the youtube channel and on the studio dash board the stream health is being shown as 'excellent' or 'good' all the time. I assume, the stream health being shown as excellent means my feed meets the container and codec requirements mandated by youtube.
Note : I am not claiming the content id as we are still in testing phase of our product.
Please advise.

Consider provide the code you're using both here and on [Issue Tracker
(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).
